# Cannot display source code from JSFiddle to blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I have a problem with my source code. I hope you read well and understand and do not immediately act ignorant of my question.
I very often come across people who are smart but don't like to understand other people's questions.

I've edited a quiz via JSFiddle. With the help of this forum, It works fine on JSFiddle.

But when I tried this source code on blogger, it didn't work very well. The question doesn't arise. Someone said that something was wrong with the CSS. I edited the CSS, but it didn't work. Even when I delete the entire CSS, the questions still don't appear while the rest of the section appears.

I will show the difference with the following image.
[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

The first image is an image that works well in JSField. The second image is the appearance of blogger with full CSS. The third image is the appearance of blogger without CSS. The CSS I mean is the CSS I use on JSField.

I have changed the contents several times, even deleted some parts. But in the end it didn't work and I returned the CSS.

One thing is for sure, even though I tried the question and answer choices from the quizzes it didn't appear on blogger.

I have asked this many times, I hope to find answers to my questions in this forum.
here I give [my file](https://jsfiddle.net/Eddys/umt9a0q2/2/) link in JSFiddle

and here's the CSS for my problem. I apologize for showing all the CSS because I don't know which part is the problem in blogger

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab');


.quizArea{
  width: 95%;
 margin:  auto;
 padding:10px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 }
.mc_quiz{
    color: #3a5336;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}



.multipleChoiceQues{
  width:90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
   
}
.quizBox
{
    width:90%;
    margin: auto;

}

.question{
    text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.buttonArea
{
    text-align: right;
    height: 4.5em;
}

button {
    height: 4em;
    width:130px;
    padding: 1.5em auto;
    margin: 1em auto;
    background-color:#f1f2ec;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #7aa4a9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1); 
    
}

#next:hover,
#submit:hover,
.viewanswer:hover,
.viewchart:hover,
.backBtn:hover,
.replay:hover {
  letter-spacing: 0.8em;
}
.viewanswer,
.viewchart,
.replay{
    width: 30%;
}

.backBtn{
    width:100px;
    height: 2em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-left: 70%;
}
#next:active,
#submit:active,
.viewanswer:active,
.viewchart:active,
.backBtn:active,
.replay:active  {
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}

.resultArea{
    display: none;
    width:70%;
    margin: auto;
    
    padding: 10px;
    
}

.chartBox{
    width: 60%;
    margin:auto;
}

.resultPage1{
    
    text-align: center;
    
}
.resultBox h1{
    
}

.briefchart
{
    text-align:center;
}

.resultBtns{
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.resultPage2,
.resultPage3
{
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.allAnswerBox{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

._resultboard{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 2%;
    height: 190px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom: 0.6px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    
}

._resultboard:nth-child(even){
    
    
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-left: 0.6px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
._resultboard:nth-last-child(2),
._resultboard:nth-last-child(1){
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

._header{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    height: 90px;
}

._yourans,
._correct{
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 5px; 
}
._correct{
    background: #968089 ;
}
.h-correct{
    background: #968089;

}

.h-correct:after,
._correct:after {
  line-height: 1.4;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 499;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00c";
  bottom: 0;
  right: 7px;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  color: #2dceb1;
}
.h-incorrect{
    background: #ab4e6b ;
}
.h-incorrect:after {
  line-height: 1.4;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 499;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00d";
  bottom: 0;
  right: 7px;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  color: #ff383e;
}

.resultPage3 h1,
.resultPage1 h1,
.resultPage2 h1{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1.3px solid rgba(21, 63, 101,0.9);
    color: #3a5336;
}

.my-progress {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 3rem auto 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 950px;
}

progress {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.5px;
    left: 5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
       appearance: none;
  background: #f1f2ec ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5px;
  background: none;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  will-change: contents;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #c72828;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color:#153f65;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.my-progress-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #7aa4a9;
  border: 3px solid #f1f2ec;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
          transition-delay: .3s;
  will-change: transform;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_1 {
  left: 0;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_2 {
  left: 9%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_3 {
  left: 18%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_4{
  left: 27%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_5 {
  left: 36%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_6 {
  left: 45%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_7 {
  left: 54%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_8 {
  left: 63%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_9 {
  left: 72%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_10 {
  left: 81%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_11 {
  left: 90%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.progress_12 {
  left: 100%;
}
.my-progress-indicator.active {
  -webkit-animation: bounce .5s forwards;
          animation: bounce .5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
          animation-delay: .5s;
  border-color: #153f65 ;
 
}

.animation-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  will-change: padding;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form-step {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}

.form-step.leaving {
  -webkit-animation: left-and-out .5s forwards;
          animation: left-and-out .5s forwards;
}

.form-step.waiting {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
          transform: translateX(400px);
}

.form-step.coming {
  -webkit-animation: right-and-in .5s forwards;
          animation: right-and-in .5s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes left-and-out {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
            transform: translateX(-400px);
  }
}

@keyframes left-and-out {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
            transform: translateX(-400px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes right-and-in {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes right-and-in {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
            transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
            transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 220px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    height:30px;
}
label{
    color: #c72828;
  
}
label:before {
    
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background : #c72828;
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
        top: calc(50% - 13px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 15px);
    cursor: pointer;
  
}

.bullet {
    
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    left: -3px;
    top: 2px;
    border: 5px solid #fff ;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .bullet {
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: explode;
    animation-duration: 0.350s;
  background : #fff;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #c72828 ;
    opacity:0;
}

.line.zero {
    left: 11px;
    top: -21px;
    transform: translateY(20px);
    width: 2px;
    height: 10px;
}

.line.one {
    right: -7px;
    top: -11px;
    transform: rotate(-55deg) translate(-9px);
}

.line.two {
    right: -20px;
    top: 11px;
    transform: translate(-9px);
}

.line.three {
    right: -8px;
    top: 35px;
    transform: rotate(55deg) translate(-9px);
}

.line.four {
    left: -8px;
    top: -11px;
    transform: rotate(55deg) translate(9px);
}

.line.five {
    left: -20px;
    top: 11px;
    transform: translate(9px);
}

.line.six {
    left: -8px;
    top: 35px;
    transform: rotate(-55deg) translate(9px);
}

.line.seven {
    left: 11px;
    bottom: -21px;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    width: 2px;
    height: 10px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .bullet .line.zero{
    animation-name:drop-zero;
    animation-delay: 0.100s;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .bullet .line.one{
    animation-name:drop-one;
    animation-delay: 0.100s;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .bullet .line.two{
    animation-name:drop-two;
    animation-delay: 0.100s;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .bullet .line.three{
    animation-name:drop-three;
    animation-delay: 0.100s;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .bullet .line.four{
    animation-name:drop-four;
    animation-delay: 0.100s;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .bullet .line.five{
    animation-name:drop-five;
    animation-delay: 0.100s;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .bullet .line.six{
    animation-name:drop-six;
    animation-delay: 0.100s;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .bullet .line.seven{
    animation-name:drop-seven;
    animation-delay: 0.100s;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes explode {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(10);
    }
    60%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes drop-zero {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(20px);
        height: 10px;
    }
    20% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-2px);
        height: 0px;
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@keyframes drop-one {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotate(-55deg) translate(-20px);
        width: 10px;
    }
    20% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(-55deg) translate(9px);
        width: 0px;
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@keyframes drop-two {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-20px);
        width: 10px;
    }
    20% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(9px);
        width: 0px;
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@keyframes drop-three {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotate(55deg) translate(-20px);
        width: 10px;
    }
    20% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(55deg) translate(9px);
        width: 0px;
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@keyframes drop-four {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotate(55deg) translate(20px);
        width: 10px;
    }
    20% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(55deg) translate(-9px);
        width: 0px;
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@keyframes drop-five {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(20px);
        width: 10px;
    }
    20% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-9px);
        width: 0px;
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@keyframes drop-six {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotate(-55deg) translate(20px);
        width: 10px;
    }
    20% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(-55deg) translate(-9px);
        width: 0px;
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@keyframes drop-seven {
0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
        height: 10px;
    }
    20% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(2px);
        height: 0px;
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

and if you want to see it in blogger view, [click here](http://spamblogging.blogspot.com/2020/08/var-progressvalue-0var-resultlist-const.html)